# Laravel push new key to array

Tags: php, laravel

I have array data like this

[image]

I want to add new key `expected_count` to the array with `if` conditional,

```
if flags key == is_join ? expected_count=2
if flags key == is_grade ? expected_count=1
```

So the result will be like this

[image]

How the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use foreach to iterate over the array

```
foreach($data['sections'] as $key => $section){
     if(array_key_exists('is_join', $section['flags'])){
         $data['sections'][$key]['flags']['is_join']['expected_count'] = 2;
     }
     if(array_key_exists('is_grade', $section['flags'])){
         $data['sections'][$key]['flags']['is_grade']['expected_count'] = 1;
     }
}
```

I hope this will work.

Comment: @AndiSiswanto Glad to hear, If it solved your issue please accept the answer and close the question ;)